# Relationship between alignment of class fields and alignment of object instances in C++?

Tags: c++, class, oop, memory-management, alignment

Given the following C++ class:

```
class X {
public:
    uint8_t a;
    uint32_t b[256] __attribute__((aligned(32)));
};
```

How can the compiler ensure that the storage for `b` is 32-byte aligned, when an instance of `X` is presumably word-aligned? Does the `aligned` attribute only specify alignment relative to the object instance start address? If so, what is the right way to make `b` 32-byte aligned relative to the address space? Should I simply specify object instance alignment using using `class alignof(32) X {...}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard says following:

[[basic.align/2]](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.align#2)

> A fundamental alignment is represented by an alignment less than or equal to the greatest alignment supported by the implementation in all contexts, which is equal to alignof(std​::​max_­align_­t) ([support.types]). The alignment required for a type may be different when it is used as the type of a complete object and when it is used as the type of a subobject.
> [Example 1:
>
> ```
> struct B { long double d; };
> struct D : virtual B { char c; };
> ```
>
> When D is the type of a complete object, it will have a subobject of type B, so it must be aligned appropriately for a long double. If D appears as a subobject of another object that also has B as a virtual base class, the B subobject might be part of a different subobject, reducing the alignment requirements on the D subobject. — end example]

And [[dcl.align/5]](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.align#5):

> The combined effect of all alignment-specifiers in a declaration shall not specify an alignment that is less strict than the alignment that would be required for the entity being declared if all alignment-specifiers appertaining to that entity were omitted.
>
> ```cpp
> [Example 1:
> struct alignas(8) S {};
> struct alignas(1) U {
>  S s;
> };  // error: U specifies an alignment that is less strict than if the alignas(1) >were omitted.
> — end example]
> ```

So, from the above section (especially the explanations of the examples) it can be assumed that the alignment of an object is resolved to the strictest amongst its members.

```
class X {
public:
    uint8_t a;
    alignas(32) uint32_t b[256];
};

int main() {
    X x1;
    // alignas(16) X x; // Clang error: requested alignment is less than minimum alignment of 32 for type 'X'    
    alignas(64) X x2; // OK 
    alignof(X); // 32
    alignof(x1); //32
    alignof(x2); //64
    alignof(x2.b); //32
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know it was possible to do `alignas(64) X x2`. Thanks! And I appreciate the clarification on alignment strictness. It looks like the default alignment of a class will ensure that the alignment of all fields will be honored.